# Java-Pasar positivos y negativos a una matriz (usando scanner)

Tags: java, array, bucle-for, scanner, java-util-scanner

Tengo que realizar un programa que lea números negativos y positivos y me cree una matriz, los números introducidos no debe superar el numero 10.

Este es mi código:

```
public static void main(String[] args) {
 int num = 0,num2 = 0;

 Scanner lector = new Scanner(System.in);

 System.out.print("Introduce la posicion de num");
 num = lector.nextInt();

 System.out.print("Introduce la posicion de num2");
 num2 = lector.nextInt();

 if(num>=10 && num2>=10) {
     System.out.println("no es un numero valido");
     do {
        System.out.print("Introduce la posicion de num");
     num = lector.nextInt();

     System.out.print("Introduce la posicion de num2");
     num2 = lector.nextInt(); 
     }while(num>=10 && num2>=10);
 }

 if(num<10 && num2<10) {
 int [][] matriz = new int [num][num2];


 System.out.println("La matriz introducida es:");

 mostrar(matriz,num);
 }
}

public static void mostrar(int[][]matriz,int num) {

    for (int i = 0; i < matriz.length; i++) {
        for (int j = 0; j < matriz[i].length; j++) {
            matriz[i][j] = num + i;
            System.out.print(matriz[i][j]+" ");
        }
        System.out.print("\n");
    }
}
```

Si coloco números negativos me da este error.

> Exception in thread "main" java.lang.NegativeArraySizeException: -2

Como se corregiría esto?

Comment: Lo que quieres detectar es que no te introduzcan valores negativos, es decir, `num1` y `num2` solo pueden guardar valores de `1 a 10`. Esa parte la entendí bien, lo que no comprendo es la parte donde dices, "tamaño predeterminado". Por cierto, en el método `mostrar`, nunca usas los parámetros `num` y `num2`, para que lo agregaste?

Comment: Quieres pedir dos valores por teclado y que esos valores sean las dimensiones de tu matriz. Ahora el problema es que si ingresa una dimensión con valor negativo, como por ejemplo: `N: -1 x M: -5`, te dará la excepción. Entonces, lo quieres es que el usuario pueda ingresar números negativos o positivos pero que no supere el valor de 10?

Comment: Quiero hacer exactamente eso. Que no supere el valor 10, no se si es un ejemplo, o que su valor no sea mayor al introducido, me da a entender.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Vamos por partes, en este bloque de código hay que ser una validación más:

```
if(num>=10 && num2>=10) {
     System.out.println("no es un numero valido");
     do {
        System.out.print("Introduce la posicion de num");
     num = lector.nextInt();

     System.out.print("Introduce la posicion de num2");
     num2 = lector.nextInt(); 
     }while(num>=10 && num2>=10);
 }
```

La variable `num` y `num2` no pueden recibir los siguientes valores:

- `num` y `num2` no pueden recibir valores nulos (ceros). Debido a que, esas variables van a ser usadas para determinar las dimensiones de la matriz y no existe una matriz `0 x 0`.
- `num` y `num2` deben estar en el rango de -10 a 10, es decir, no pueden ingresar un número -12 o 12, siempre debe ser hasta 10 o -10.

También recalco, que esta condición:

```
num>=10 && num2>=10
```

Está incorrecta, porqué si `num = 20` y `num2 = 5`, el resultado dará `false` (porqué la primera condición se cumple pero la segunda no) y no mandará el mensaje de error (pues se supone que las dimensiones como máximo deben ser hasta 10). Una solución es cambiar el operador `&&` por el `||`.

El código quedaría de esta forma:

```
while(true)
{
    System.out.print("Introduce la posicion de num: ");
    num = lector.nextInt();

    System.out.print("Introduce la posicion de num2: ");
    num2 = lector.nextInt(); 
    if((num < -10 || num > 10)
 || (num2 < -10 || num2 > 10) || num == 0 || num2 == 0)
        System.out.println("no es un numero valido\n");
    else
        //Rompe el ciclo
        break;
}
```

Hasta el momento, todo marcha correctamente, hemos validado las entradas, ahora el usuario no podrá ingresar valores que no estén en el rango de -10 a 10 o valores nulos.

Ahora, el problema radica que si el usuario me ingresa un valor negativo, ya sea en `num` o en `num2`, me lanzará la siguiente excepción: 
[NegativeArraySizeException](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/lang/NegativeArraySizeException.html), esto pasa porqué no puedes crear una matriz con dimensiones negativas. ¿Pero porqué no lo puedo hacer? Porqué estarías provocando un [desbordamiento de búfer](https://es.wikipedia.org/wiki/Desbordamiento_de_b%C3%BAfer), el JVM (Java Virtual Machine) nunca dejará que esto suceda (por temas de seguridad), por esta razón te manda esa excepción y hace que el programa deje de funcionar.

Entonces, podemos plantear un algoritmo para que nuestro programa si deje ingresar valores negativos y que no suceda ninguna excepción.

- Debemos declarar una variable de tipo `boolean` para saber si el primer número ingresado por el usuario, es negativo, esto nos servirá para que podamos saber si la variable `num` en realidad es un número negativo, ya que antes de mostrar (con el método `mostrar`) la matriz, debemos asegurarnos que `num` tenga el valor negativo.
- Debemos detectar si `num` es negativo, si la condición se cumple, pasamos a convertir el valor de `num` a un número positivo. **¿Por qué es necesario hacer esto**? Esto lo hacemos para poder crear la matriz, ya que las dimensiones siempre deben ser positivas.
- Verificamos si la variable `num2` tiene un valor negativo y convertimos el valor a positivo.
- Creamos la matriz con las dimensiones `Num x Num2` y por último, necesitamos saber si la variable `num` es negativo o no (por eso es la variable de tipo `boolean`), ya que si la condición se cumple, debemos darle el valor original que tenía `num` (que era un valor negativo) y posteriormente llamaríamos al método `mostrar`.

El código quedaría así:

```
class Program
{
    public static void main(String[] arg)
    {
        int num, num2;
        boolean esNegativo = false;
        int [][] matriz;
        Scanner lector = new Scanner(System.in);

        while(true)
        {
            System.out.print("Introduce la posicion de num: ");
            num = lector.nextInt();

            System.out.print("Introduce la posicion de num2: ");
            num2 = lector.nextInt(); 
            if((num < -10 || num > 10)
 || (num2 < -10 || num2 > 10) || num == 0 || num2 == 0)
                System.out.println("no es un numero valido\n");
            else
                //Rompe el ciclo
                break;
        }

        //Si el primer número es negativo..
        if(num < 0)
        {
            //Lo convertimos a positivo..
            num = num * (-1);
            //Asignamos un "true" a la variable para saber que la variable num en realidad es NEGATIVO.
            esNegativo = true;
        }

        //Si el segundo número es negativo..
        if(num2 < 0)
            //Lo convertimos a positivo..
            num2 = num2 * (-1);

        //Creamos la matriz NxM (las dimensiones siempre deben ser positivos).
        matriz = new int[num][num2];
        System.out.println("La matriz introducida es:");

        //Si la variable num en realidad fue NEGATIVO..
        if(esNegativo == true)
            //le devolvemos el valor original (un valor negativo) a la variable num
            num = num * (-1);
        mostrar(matriz, num);
    }
}
```

Por último, podemos hacer una prueba, si `num = 2` y `num2 = 3`, nuestro programa debería dar como resultado en pantalla:

```
2 2 2
3 3 3
```

Ahora, si `num = -2` y `num = -3`, debería dar como resultado:

```
-2 -2 -2
-1 -1 -1
```

Ahora, si `num = -3` y `num = 2`, deberia dar como resultado:

```
-3 -3 
-2 -2 
-1 -1
```

Comment: Muchisimas gracias por tomarte un tiempo en leer y responder mi pregunta, tu respuesta ha sido clara y he podido entender todo y arreglar mi fallo.